# Pull all rows from one table in join even when nothing found in other table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a view with almost 7000 rows and a table, and I have in a Left join thinking I would still pull everything from the view and just be able to insert null into the UNITCOST field when applicable. However, it only pulls matching rows. Below is the code.

```
Select vto.*, vc.UNITCOST
From myView vto
LEFT JOIN VeryCost vc
ON vto.VI_ID = vc.VI_ID
Where (vc.VC_START_DATE BETWEEN '9/4/2016' AND '10/1/2016'
             OR vc.VC_END_DATE BETWEEN '9/4/2016' AND '10/1/2016')
```

So, what I want to do is select ALL rows from the view and the UNITCOST value from the VeryCost table where the VI fields match the dates are valid. When the VI fields match but the dates are not valid I want UNITCOST to be null for those rows.

Comment: The where clause is negating the left join.  Simply change the word `WHERE` to `AND`; eliminating the where clause and moving the limits to the join which will cause the limits to be applied before the join allowing all the outer join records to remain. Instead of being excluded because VC is a NULL value and the evaluation eliminates the nulls generated by the left join

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` clause it what is limiting the data. To account for non-matches from `vto`, use this:

```
Select vto.*, vc.UNITCOST
From myView vto
LEFT JOIN VeryCost vc
ON vto.VI_ID = vc.VI_ID
Where
    (vc.VI_ID is null)
    or 
    (vc.VC_START_DATE BETWEEN '9/4/2016' AND '10/1/2016' OR vc.VC_END_DATE BETWEEN '9/4/2016' AND '10/1/2016')
```

**EDIT** or you can include the date matching in the `JOIN` criteria, as another answer mentions.  Either way, just don't do anything that forces the non-matches to be excluded.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check VC.VI_ID? (foreign Key)  instead of the dates?  it may be legitimate that the dates are NULL when VC.VI_ID is populated; but this would include them.

Answer (score 1):

See comment for reasoning...

```
SELECT vto.*, vc.UNITCOST
FROM  myView vto
LEFT JOIN VeryCost vc
  ON vto.VI_ID = vc.VI_ID
 AND (vc.VC_START_DATE BETWEEN '9/4/2016' AND '10/1/2016'
   OR vc.VC_END_DATE BETWEEN '9/4/2016' AND '10/1/2016')
```

The where clause was negating the left join.

The join occurs first so the null records generated by the join exist.  Then the limits are applied since VC is on the include only those reocrds that match... NULL values will be present.  Since VC.Start_date or VC.End_date isn't taking into account nulls, the null records are being excluded, thus the where clause is negating the left join.

Comment: Thank you much for your answers!